# How to configure mongodb with express using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to connect to mongoddb to express server using mongoose ,This is first time i am working with mongodb and expres any help with basic setup will be appreciated. I am getting below `error`

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app     = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/8760');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.listen(8760, function(){
    console.log('I am listening 8760...');
});
```

model.js

```
var DiagramSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: String, ref:'User'},
  groups: [{type: String, ref: 'Group'}],
  users: [{type: String, ref: 'User'}],
  string: String
});
```

error

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first c
   at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sh529u\WebstormProjects\develop-mod
\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-cor
```

Comment: You probably mean 'mongodb://localhost:8760', not 'mongodb://localhost/8760'.

Comment: You have connect error... localhost:27017 use this string 'mongodb://localhost:8760' or 'mongodb://localhost:27017' as default

Comment: If you are using the default port you don't actually have to specify it.  Also, the name you specify after the `/` is the name of the database you want to connect to, so in this case you are saying you want to connect to the database "8760".  If you have specified a different port than the default, you'll need to connect like the others have mentioned

Comment: One other thing, are you sure the mongo service is actually running?

Comment: @Dave i tried with default port 27017 but same error, mongod.exe is running

Comment: If you open a command prompt/terminal and type `mongo` does that work?

Comment: Also are you sure that your mongo doesn't require authentication? If mongo do ..then you need to specify username and password.Example https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: @Dave Yes it works

Comment: As @MykolaBorysyuk mentioned, unless you need some authentication, using "mongodb://<server name>/<database name>" should work.  If it doesn't you have some other sort of network issue happening on your machine preventing you from connecting

Answer (score 0):

**Here's your requirement:**

*App.js*

`var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app     = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.listen(8760, function(){
    console.log('I am listening 8760...');
});`

*model.js*

`var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var DiagramSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: String, ref:'User'},
  groups: [{type: String, ref: 'Group'}],
  users: [{type: String, ref: 'User'}],
  string: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('collectionName', DiagramSchema);`

> Points to be kept in mind:

1. Mongo Server `mongod.exe` should be running at background or as service
2. Include `model.js` file where ever you want to perform database transactions.